# How to Pass address of Stucture to Void pointer[void*] in C# to VC++ Dll

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

//Structure:

```
struct MYDATA{
char calls[4069];      
char Desc[4096];   
char error[1024];     

} ;
```

//Test function

```
char *Argv[] = { "ToolName", "USername", "192.168.2", "3", "400"};  
typedef void* ( *__stdcall  pCstartSIPSessionint)(char **argv ); 
typedef struct MYDATA*(*__cdecl pgetStat) ();

pCstartSIPSessionint startSessionint = (pCstartSIPSessionint )GetProcAddress(HMODULE (hGetProcIDDLL),"startSessionint");
```

//Dll Import

```
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("E:\\MyDll.dll"));

pgetStat getStat ;
getStat = (pgetStat ) startSessionint(Argv);

MYDATA *mydata;
if(getStat != NULL)
        mydata= getStat();
printf("\n mydata\n %s ", mydata->call); 
printf("\n mydata\n %s ", mydata->summary); 
printf("\n mydata\n %s ", mydata->error);
```

How to Convert the code in C#?
And i have confused to pass address of stucture to Void* in C#
I can able to pass only values, how can pass Address to the structure.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: "this is helpfull but i struct with some lines... i thing intptr have same memory address if i run no of times... may i know y –  user3322182 " ...You'll have to show us what is inside that "callback/delegate" function...to determine why it always returns the same pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The struct should be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MYDATA
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4096)]
    public string calls;      
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4096)]
    public string Desc;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
    public string error;     
}
```

I assume the 4069 value in the question is a typo.

The first function is:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] 
public static extern IntPtr startSessionint(string[] argv);
```

Then convert the function pointer to a delegate:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate IntPtr getStatDelegate();
....
IntPtr ptr = startSessionint(argv);
if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
    // handle error
getStatDelegate getStat = (getStatDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(getStatDelegate));
```

Now you can call the function:

```
IntPtr structPtr = getStat();
```

And then marshal to the struct:

```
MYDATA data = (MYDATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(structPtr, typeof(MYDATA));
```

Comment: It Working But it throw the warning/error like -------
@Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'c:\users\vts\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\AppNew\AppNew\bin\Debug\AppNew.exe'.

Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'AppNew!AppNew.Form1::startSessionint' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, perhaps startSessionint is really cdecl.

Comment: I bet it really is cdecl. Do you have the implementation.

Comment: [DllImport(@"E:\\MyDll.dll",CallingConvention =CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr startSessionint(string[] argv);
string[] argv ={"Name","ID","192.168.1.2","2","420"};
ptr=startSIPSessionint(argv); May i know if the code is correct and my error is "A call to PInvoke function 'DllImport!DllImport.DllCall::startSessionint' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature.Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature".plz give the solution

Comment: No, I mean the implementation of the function in the dll. The C++ code you have could be wrong. It's certainly odd that one function is cdecl and the other stdcall. But the code in my answer matches that in the question. So I guess the code in the Q doesn't match the dll implementation.

Comment: Yah now i change Cdel sir., how to pass value to this c++ funtion  [ @void *WINAPI startSessionint (char *argv[]);] in C#...

Comment: Pass a `string[]`. That's just standard C#.

Comment: hi david, if i pass string[] it not wornking.... and if pass like" public static extern IntPtr startSessionint([In] IntPtr args); " it also not give exact result for me... Why

Comment: It works fine here. A week has passed. I've no idea what your code looks like now. I think I've answered the question you aked.

Comment: this is helpfull but i struct with some lines... i thing intptr have same memory address if i run no of times... may i know y

Comment: Never mind. I can offer no more. I answered the question that you asked.