# How To P/Invoke char* [] in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

How To P/Invoke `char* []` in C#

Any 1 tell how to continue hereafter.
I want to send parameters to C++ DLL from C#. I had googled many sites but no solution.

C Function

```
public void* find(char*[] argv)
{
}
```

C# Function
i want invoke this function with following paramter arguments

```
char *Argv[] = { "Tool", "Sachin", "192.168.1.1", "3", "400"};
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [This might help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17450/Marshal-an-Array-of-Zero-Terminated-Strings-or-Str)

Comment: i already visit that...kindly I need another solution

Comment: That's not enough information. C++ arrays and pointers don't have size information. At the very least, you'd want to pass a separate `int` to say how many strings there are (assuming those should be zero terminated strings).

Comment: It is just a string[].  The function can never figure out how many strings are in the array so it cannot work correctly.  You need to fix and unit-test C++ code *before* you try to pinvoke it.  Doing it afterwards just makes it a lot more difficult to discover the design mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it...here are just a couple...but I outline other information you need to be aware of.

---

### Properly Exporting/Importing your "find" Function

First you need to make sure your "exported" C function and the `DllImport` are defined properly (if you have this working already, then ignore this section).

If your C function is compiled to use the `cdecl` calling convention (usually the default in C/C++ projects), then you need to use `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` on the `DllImport` e.g.

```
[DllImport("yourdll.dll", CharSet = Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public IntPtr find([In] String[] args);
```

If your C function is compiled to use the 'stdcall' calling convention (by project options or by putting the WINAPI macro, or __stdcall decoration on the function definition), then you need to use `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall` (which is the default on DllImport anyway) e.g.

```
[DllImport("yourdll.dll", CharSet = Ansi)]
public IntPtr find([In] String[] args);
```

In addition when defining a "C" function you can use `extern "C"` to stop the the C++ compiler mangling the name of the function.

You then either use `__declspec(export)`, or use a .DEF file to specify the function as an exported entry.

---

### What is your "find" Contract?

Important: you need to know the contract of your "find" function...i.e. what will it look for to signify the "end" of that list of arguments...it might use NULL, or it might use an empty string, etc.

Usually, functions like that, have another parameter that signifies the "count" of the number of items in the array so that a "marker" isn't needed.

For the example below, I will assume it uses NULL at the end...you will have to modify the code accordingly if it's not that way.

If it's possible for some of your parameters to be NULL, then you will have to change the "sentinel" used to signify the end.

---

### You can do the "marshalling" between C# and native types (using the Marshalling attributes):

```
    // Note: this uses a "NULL" to mark the end of the array...
    // because your "find" function doesn't have a "count" parameter, and I'm
    // assuming it uses a NULL parameter to detect the end. 

    IntPtr opaqueresult = find(new string[] { "Tool", "Sachin", "192.168.1.1", "3", "400", null});  // call the function in that DLL.
```

---

### Or you can do the marshaling logic yourself (rearrange and expand the code as necessary to clean up memory etc):

```
// When need to use IntPtr as we are allocating the native memory.
[DllImport("yourdll.dll", CharSet = Ansi)]
public IntPtr find([In] IntPtr args);

IntPtr []allocatednativestrings;
IntPtr args = AllocateAnsiIntPtrArrayWithSentinel( new string[] { "Tool", "Sachin", "192.168.1.1", "3", "400"}, out allocatednativestrings);

IntPtr opaqueresult = find(args);  // call the function in that DLL.

// If "find" DOESN'T hold onto the pointers passed into it, then you can "free"
// the memory just after you make the call....otherwise you can't...you then
// have to decide how/who has responsibility for freeing that memory and when.

// Free the "strings", and the memory containing the pointers
FreeAnsiIntPtrArrayWithSentinel(args, allocatednativestrings);

(Note: I am only using this bit of hacky code, as it was mentioned in a comment above...
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17450/Marshal-an-Array-of-Zero-Terminated-Strings-or-Str ....
the crucial thing is to make sure you "free" the memory properly, when you are finished with it....
this can be done neater...just giving you enough to get the idea) 

public static IntPtr AllocateAnsiIntPtrArrayWithSentinel(string[] InputStrArray, out IntPtr[] InPointers)
{
    int size = InputStrArray.Length + 1; // +1 for NULL sentinel

    //build array of pointers to string
    InPointers = new IntPtr[size];

    int dim = IntPtr.Size * size;

    IntPtr rRoot = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(dim);

    int i = 0;
    foreach(string arg in args)
    {
        if (arg == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, "this code needs changing to support NULL arguments");
        }

        InPointers[i++] = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(arg);
    }

    // The NULL sentinel...don't need to do this as already initialized to null...
    // but just making it clearer for you.
    InPointers[size-1] = IntPtr.Zero;

    //copy the array of pointers
    Marshal.Copy(InPointers, 0, rRoot, size);
    return rRoot;
} 

public static void FreeAnsiIntPtrArrayWithSentinel(IntPtr args, IntPtr[] intptrs)
{
    foreach(IntPtr ptr in intptrs)
    {
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) // we need to avoid the sentinel
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr); // free the mem allocated for the string
    }

    // free the memory that contained the list of string pointers and sentinel
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(args);
}
```

Comment: another example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317931/marshal-an-array-of-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-code-using-p-invoke ... and be careful on how you are "exporting" the function from your DLL...i.e. which calling convention you use i.e. cdecl or stdcall

Comment: I wouldn't use generics for that. Just make two methods or pass a `bool` instead. This really isn't clear usage of generics at all.

Comment: I agree...I was just using the example mentioned in the other comment/link

Comment: If clear the memory of args it return null only..... kindly help for clear the memory

Comment: @colinsmith hi, check this link, i have posted the another question in it.. kindly i need the solution of both... because two question are about the same proble.. please refer and help me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111918/how-to-pass-address-of-stucture-to-void-pointervoid-in-c-sharp-to-vc-dll

Comment: My Code is in that link kindly send the solution

Comment: Error on "InPointers[size-1] = null;" the error is "Cannot convert null to 'System.IntPtr' because it is a non-nullable value type "

Comment: InPointers[size-1] = IntPtr.Zero

Comment: hi  colinsmith... Kindly see the link.. i hope it was helpfull for me

Comment: hi genius colonsmith, I need how to call the c++ typedef in c# by using of delegate function... kindly help ... my code is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111918/how-to-pass-address-of-stucture-to-void-pointervoid-in-c-sharp-to-vc-dll

Comment: @user3322182 Unaccepting good answers as a means to hopefully strong arm an answerer into helping you on a different question pretty much sucks. You've unaccepted two good answers in that way, and failed to accept another one. It seems to me that you don't really understand what Stack Overflow is about.

Comment: Thank's for such a simple solution, I was trying to play with unmanaged memory, but in the end a simple array + add a null value with a [in] parameter do the magic.